# Segmentation fault : 11, with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

a problem that I am not able to resolve...

I have a segmentation fault when I call the new_col() function.
Structs are OK, function not.

```
typedef struct {
    int jour;
    int mois;
    int annee;
} date;

typedef struct {
    date** tab;
    int size;
} col_dates;

// Fonction B1.c
col_dates* new_col(int size) {

   int i;
   col_dates* cd;

   for(i=0; i<size; i++) {

       cd->tab[i] = NULL;

   }

   cd->size = i;

   return cd;

}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: This is such a FAQ. Surely there must be a good duplicate for "I try to store random stuff through an uninitialized pointer" somewhere? Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`col_dates *cd;` is *a pointer* which doesn't point to anything. It doesn't have any *memory* to point to and thus, no *data* to point to. So you can't just do `cd->data;`, because *`data` is not there* (you're trying to access *nothing* and getting a segfault).

You have to allocate memory first:

```
col_dates *cd = malloc(sizeof(col_dates));

// access cd and return it
```

After you allocate `cd`, allocate `cd->tab` as well:

```
cd->tab = malloc(size * sizeof(date *));
```

Don't forget to `free` the pointer returned after you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Should not be `cd->tab = malloc(size * sizeof(date*));` ? tab is intended to be an array of pointers.

Comment: @DavideSpataro, yep, it should, thanks for noticing this!

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot the malloc() :)

Comment: Better yet: `malloc( sizeof(date*[size]) );`